# EF Core - how to seed data with different relationships?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following 4 models:

```
public class Character
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string RpgClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Weapon))]
    public int WeaponId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Damage { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Character))]
    public int CharacterId { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using InMemoryDb and would like to seed these data from JSON files. I have configured the relationships, but always get this message:

***"The seed entity for entity type 'Character' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Weapon' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'Weapon' and specify the foreign key values {'CharacterId'}."***

I have seen it on Microsoft's website that the .HasData needs to be called in a certain way during configuring the relationships, but wasn't able to figure it out how.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        List<Character> characters = ParseJson<Character>("./SeedData/characters.json");
        List<Skill> skills = ParseJson<Skill>("./SeedData/skills.json");
        List<User> users = ParseJson<User>("./SeedData/users.json");
        List<Weapon> weapons = ParseJson<Weapon>("./SeedData/weapons.json");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Character>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Weapon)
            .WithOne(e => e.Character)
            .HasForeignKey<Weapon>(e => e.CharacterId)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Character>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Skills)
            .WithMany(e => e.Characters);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Characters)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Weapon>().HasData(weapons);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Character>().HasData(characters);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().HasData(skills);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(users);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When seeding data, you can't set relationship objects directly, but you have to set the foreign keys instead. However, if your Ids are generated in the database, then the seeder has no way of matching up the relationships.

Your options are to change completely to client side generation of your keys (probably not what you want).

You can also set the keys explicitely, but then you would need to add custom logic to the resulting migration that:

- Set Identity Insert to ON for each table before inserting and OFF again afterwards (depending on your DB)
- Possibly update the seeder to not generate those initial values

See also: [.NET Core Entity Framework seeding data relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039293/net-core-entity-framework-seeding-data-relations)